# How can I return the results of many IDs associated to a record during lookup?

Tags: flow, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I am using a flow which works on the task and event related to opportunity.The flow works for updating the task/event with their whatid(opportunity) and whoid(contact). It works fine for one record of the event/task but when i create multiple tasks/events for that particular record it doesn't work for multiple entries and update tasks/events.[image]

Trying using Fast Lookup but how to use the loop with the decision for updating multiple tasks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [FAST LOOKUPS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_fast_lookup.htm) in visual flows .Fast lookup allows you to fetch collection of record rather than single records in flows

See the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Want to understand one thing, if I use FAST LOOKUPS instead of RECORD LOOKUP then do I have to use LOOPS as well, moreover if I use LOOPS then I have to use RECORD UPDATE or FAST UPDATE

Comment: You will use FAST UPDATE ! Please mark as answered if that helped you and answers !